# Python middleware gzip - Nginx Etags not working

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, http-headers, gzip

In our stack, the python middleware is doing the gzip not nginx. So even if I turn on the Etags on Nginx level ( HTTP block ) I couldn't see the Etags in the response headers ( neither strong nor weak ) .

Is it necessary that gzip has to be done on nginx level to make Etags work ? Or is there a solution for it as well ?
Can someone please suggest ?

Comment: Issue got resolved . It was due to the fact the we were not passing the Etags correctly to the nginx from Python .

Comment: `etag on;`  configuration under the location block was enough for nginx .